# Converting dbf into raster image using Python as way to add table to layout?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, attribute-table, layouts

ArcPy does not have a function to add a table to a layout.

I was thinking that maybe taking that table (e.g. a dbf), there may be some python script command to turn it into a raster (e.g. do something like a screen capture on the table).

You could then add the screen capture raster image to the layout using arcpy.

Anyone know of a function in python, or a few lines of python code to do this?

Answer (score 3):

From ESRI:

> The following script will construct a graphic table based on data values from a table in the map document. The map document was authored with a vertical line named vertLine, a horizontal line named horzLine, and a text element named TableText. Each of the elements were authored with the appropriate symbology properties. The element's anchors were also set to the upper left position and the text element's vertical and horizontal justification were set to top left.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000040000000

Edit - To clarify, the script and the quoted paragraph are about 2/3 of the way down in the article.